# Python Machine learning Web Api

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask

Hi I would like to do a machine learning hello world, e.g. the Iris data set. I would then like to create a web API (RESTful service) to allow a HTTP Post request to send over (petal_length, sepal_length) and get back the prediction on the type of Iris.

I intend to use Scikit learn but what should I use to make a web API? what do people normally use to make a ML Web API?

Django, I know about this for making websites but I am not sure if it is used for web APIs. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Flask, I have also heard about this one but never used it before. http://flask.pocoo.org/

I would like to write unit tests and integration tests. It will also need to use authentication to ensure users have access. Currently my Web API for authenticating users is an ASP.Net Core Web Api and I use JWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask is just fine for ML API purposes only. It took me very little time to install and configure Flask API and write first API functions calling 3rd party ML API and reformulate its feedback matching to needs. I have added internal ML classifiers modification and usage API functions later.

Instructions:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link also.